# Does Word 2016 Add-Ins support the use of RESTful call

Tags: office-js

With Word 2016 Add-Ins, can I use a Restful call to send the Word document onto a Network Server once saved.

Answer (score 4):

With Office.js you can get the document as either docx or pdf  (using [getFileAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync)) and then use any REST service you  (including OneDrive API through Graph) to upload it to a specific end point.

Comment: I think it is worth to add that you are not sending files directly. You are just sending their ids and a token and your server needs to download it directly from the Exchange Server

Comment: in this specific instance, thats not the case. the dev actually gets the file and then using graph uploads.

Comment: you are right. I mixed this stack question with another one regarding attachments.